# allow eth0 connections to communicate with WLAN and internet

Tags: networking

Runing arm64 Bullseye on Raspberry Pi3

The Use Case is:

- Sky router running DHCP server.
- All devices connected via WiFi to Sky router.
- Successfully connected a Pi via WiFi to the router. Network all good.
  Next...
- I want to be able to add an IP camera to the LAN port [eth0] and obtain IP addresses from the Sky router which is reachable via wlan0.  The cam is PoE and cable only, no wifi. i have a PoE injector and lan cable from that to the pi.

I am not sure if this is even possible. Aside , any device on the network neefs to be able to communicate with the cam. it would be nice if i can get comms working the other way, from eth0 to internet via wlan0 but for now just one way would be a start.

when i connect the cam.to eth0 it gets a local link ip 164.x.y.z so something needs doing.

I dont know what the networking term is for this so id be keen to know but ive read about bridging,  vlans and dhcpcd ... i can't say i know which is what and what to chose.

help!

I have tried two guides which didnt work and I had to reflash the SDcard twice. Kind of need some help please.

https://sureshjoshi.com/development/ras ... -ethernet-
viewtopic.php?t=193770#:~:text=The%20wa ... 0bridge%22.

Comment: would this be along the lines? https://gojimmypi.github.io/raspberry-pi-network-eth0-to-wlan0/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address on Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os)

Comment: If you try the above and have problems post DETAILS of what you tried and DIAGNOSTICS. Your question is too vague.

Comment: please fix the link to the guides

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a bridge between the WiFi and Ethernet and that's not feasible.

So you need to configure routing and masquerading between WiFi and Ethernet and I recommend that you add DHCP for easy IP administration on the Ethernet interface.

A recent guide that takes you through the steps could be this one:

https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-wifi-bridge/

Comment: How is "a bridge not feasible"?  That's exactly what that guide is about, so perhaps there is a typo here.  However, a bridge is not necessary; you will need a DHCP server, then you port forward the camera's HTTP(S) server or whatever to the internet.  It does not  need to get its own external address.  If you search for "linux ip camera port forwarding" (or leave out "ip camera", since it is exactly the same) you will find plenty of examples.

Comment: The solution is a routed solution and thats not a bridge.

Comment: <_< I only glanced at it and you are right, all apologies.  We are talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the camera to obtain IP address from "Sky router" then only way is to turn RPi into a bridge. You need to create bridge interface and assign both Ethernet and Wi-Fi to it as slave interfaces. There is answer on unix&linux that  should get you started.

[Configuring bridge on debian (ifup)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363332/how-do-i-configure-a-network-interface-bridge-from-wifi-to-ethernet-with-debian)

Make sure that your Wi-Fi access point DOES NOT have AP/client/wireless isolation option turned on. This will prevent communication between Wi-Fi clients (other devices on Wi-Fi won't be able to talk to camera or even RPi).